# add value to dictionary key as list loop for

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to add a list of value for a key.
I use the following lines :

```
d = dict()

for i in range(5):
    d['key'].append(i)
```

But I get the error : KeyError: 'key'

The expected output is : {'key' : [0,1,2,3,4]}

How to fix this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't append to a nonexistent list. Initialize `d['key']` first.

```
d = {'key': []}
for i in range(5):
    d['key'].append(i)
```

Comment: this is probably the simplest and explains the issue

Answer (score 1):

Just another unmentioned way, for the one liners:

```
d = {'key' : [i for i in range(5)]}
```

This is called *comprehension* in python: [python comprehension](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comprehensions-in-python/)

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {}
xkey =1
i=[]
for x in range(5):
  i.append(x)
d[xkey] = i
print(d)
```

The result

```
{1: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Comment: Don't forget to elaborate a bit as to how you arrived at this answer or what your code means for people just starting out. Nice answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `defaultdict` to create automatically an object for a missing key, in this case an empty list.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for i in range(5):
    d['key'].append(i)

print(d)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'key': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has no way to know that the values for the key `key` are a list. First you should initialize the key and then append the values like:

```py
d = dict()
d['key'] = []

for i in range(5):
    d['key'].append(i) 
    
print(d)
# {'key': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a dict that *might* contain `'key'`, I would write this with a try/except over `KeyError` and start the list if it doesn't exist

```py
for i in range(5):
    try:
        d['key'].append(i)
    except KeyError:    # key not in d (yet)
        d['key'] = [i]  # start a new list
```

Comment: While this is the traditional way to write things like this, Python has better ways like `defaultdict` and `.setdefault()`. I wouldn't recommend this in new code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all what are you trying to accomplish here? If you want to create a list value for that key you should do it like

```
d['key'] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Anyway, the problem in your code is that you are trying to append a value in a list that does not exist. A solution to your problem could be

```
d = dict()

for i in range(5):
    if 'key' not in d.keys():
        d['key'] = []
    else:
        d['key'].append(i)
```